# Data binding from a partial view in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to bind a data from partial view to index it is binding in same view but not other view.I tried like this

```js
    $scope.GetDelete = function (cy_name) {
        $scope.items = cy_name;
        //$scope.newItem = { title: '' };
        alert($scope.items);

    }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger margin-inline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dvDelete" ng-click="GetDelete('@item.cy_name')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

```html
                <div class="modal fade" id="dvDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Are you sure?</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>{{items}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"ng-click="GetDelete('Test')">Delete</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Modal is showing but nothing data

Comment: Does the modal come within the scope of the controller?

Answer (score 0):

For the scope variable to be available within your modal, the modal code needs to fall within the scope of the controller. If it is defined outside the scope, the modal template wouldn't be aware of the existence of the scope.

```js
 angular.module('myapp', [])
   .controller('myctrl', function($scope) {


     $scope.GetDelete = function(cy_name) {
       $scope.items = cy_name;
       //$scope.newItem = { title: '' };
       alert($scope.items);
     }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div ng-app='myapp' ng-controller='myctrl' class="modal fade" id="dvDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Are you sure?</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{items}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="GetDelete('Test')">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger margin-inline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dvDelete" ng-click="GetDelete('@item.cy_name')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</button>
```

Here is a working snippet

Comment: But the button click is not the same view

Comment: Then you should create a directive out of the modal and pass on the scope to it

Comment: tankyou let me try